# Fields for arrays of strings/numbers in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm working on some connectors for Google Data Studio for our company, and I am wondering if there is any way to represent an array of strings/numbers as a field.

Currently I am returning an array of strings as a comma separated "string", which isn't that useful in calculated fields, so was wondering if there is a better way to represent this array?